# Evento botón onclick ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

no sabía como llamar a mi pregunta y es que después de pasar un par de horas intentando hacerlo por mi cuenta y buscando tutoriales no he podido, recurro a este foro a ver si alguien me echa un cable :(

Lo que busco es agregar un evento a un botón que diga "Loading" mentras se completa la acción por ajax. Específicamente es este botón https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/spinners/ el último que dice click me.

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
        ajaxPost: function(data){
        $('#loading').slideDown(250);
        //DETERMINAR TIPO DE PRIVACIDAD
        privacidad = $('.marcado').attr('data-value');          
        //
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: global_data.url + '/muro-stream.php?do=post&type=' + muro.stream.type,
            data: 'adj=' + muro.stream.adjunto +'&data=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '&pid=' + $('#info').attr('pid') + '&privacidad=' + privacidad,
            success: function(h){
                switch(h.charAt(0)){
                    case '0': //Error
                        mydialog.alert('Error al publicar', h.substring(3));                            
                    break;
                    case '1': //OK
                        // ESCONDEMOS SI ES EL PRIMER COMENTARIO
                        if($('#solouno')) $('#solouno').hide();
                        //
                        $('#wall-content, #news-content, #destacados-content, #populares-content, #publico-content').prepend($(h.substring(3)).fadeIn('slow'));
                        $('#wall').val('').focus();
                        muro.stream.load('status',$('#stMain'));
                        $('#privami').find('a').removeClass('marcado');
                        //$.scrollTo($('#news-content'), 500);
                    break;
                }
                $('#loading').slideUp(350); 
            },
            complete: function (){
                // LOADER/ STATUS
                muro.stream.loader(false);
                muro.stream.status = 0;
                $('#loading').fadeOut(350); 
            }
        });
    },
```

Mi botón es este:

```
<button type="button" id="btn-one" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="muro.stream.compartir();">Click me!</button>
```

Pero lo que no se es dónde o cómo integrar este script del botón:

```
$('#btn-one').click(function() {
$('#btn-one').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
 });
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ayúdate con los métodos [`beforeSend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y [`complete`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de AJAX para controlar tu petición, como bien se dice, antes de enviarlo y cuando ésta se completa.

Según tu [documentación con el spinner](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/spinners/) que quieres usar, esto sería así:

1. Agrega tu HTML del `spinner` que quieres usar, es decir, agrega un elemento y agrégale un id para manipularlo. **Este código lo debes de poner en tu documento HTML de una manera ordinaria en tu archivo `.html`**:

---

```
<div style="display:none;" id="mi-spinner" class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

---

2. Agregamos el `beforeSend` en tu petición AJAX para mostrar el spinner que está escondido desde un inicio con la propiedad css añadida `display:none`

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: global_data.url + '/muro-stream.php?do=post&type=' + muro.stream.type,
    data: 'adj=' + muro.stream.adjunto +'&data=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '&pid=' + $('#info').attr('pid') + '&privacidad=' + privacidad,
    beforeSend : function() {
      $("#mi-spinner").hide();
    },
    success: function(h){
        switch(h.charAt(0)){
            case '0': //Error
                mydialog.alert('Error al publicar', h.substring(3));                            
            break;
            case '1': //OK
                // ESCONDEMOS SI ES EL PRIMER COMENTARIO
                if($('#solouno')) $('#solouno').hide();
                //
                $('#wall-content, #news-content, #destacados-content, #populares-content, #publico-content').prepend($(h.substring(3)).fadeIn('slow'));
                $('#wall').val('').focus();
                muro.stream.load('status',$('#stMain'));
                $('#privami').find('a').removeClass('marcado');
                //$.scrollTo($('#news-content'), 500);
            break;
        }
        $('#loading').slideUp(350); 
    },
    complete: function (){
        // LOADER/ STATUS
        muro.stream.loader(false);
        muro.stream.status = 0;
        $('#loading').fadeOut(350); 
        $("#mi-spinner").show();
    }
});
```

---

Observa cómo agregamos esta parte al código para mostrar el spinner antes de iniciar la petición:

```
    ...
    beforeSend : function() {
      $("#mi-spinner").hide();
    }
    ...
```

También, hemos modificado es parte de tu código para que al completar la petición ajax con errores o no, se esconda ese elemento con el `$("#mi-spinner").hide();`:

```
    ...
    complete: function (){
        // LOADER/ STATUS
        muro.stream.loader(false);
        muro.stream.status = 0;
        $('#loading').fadeOut(350); 
        $("#mi-spinner").hide();
    }
    ...
```

Esto debería de funcionarte para lograr tu objetivo de mostrar y ocultar el spinner en la petición ajax.

**Actualización**

Te agregué y solucioné algunos errores de sintaxis y también que el elemento debe ocultarse en el `complete` y en el `beforeSend` mostrarse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme amigo. He puesto el código como me lo has indicado y tengo este error en la consola:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

La línea del error es:

success: function(h){

Comment: Por favor ve la actualización, faltaba una coma entre la llave que cierra del beforeSend y donde empieza el success

Comment: Le faltabuna "," antes de success:

Comment: Funciona bien solo que al enviar el estado (que es la función) no desaparece el loader pero ya con esta explicación y datos que me diste puedo guiarme ya que además encontré un buen tutorial en youtube. Muchas gracias amigo, me ha servido muchísimo.